# .Net Application Insights 2.5 not tracking HTTP requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I have a ASP .Net MVC app which is using Application Insights for telemetry tracking. It works fine when debugging the application from any developer machine with localhost, but when deployed to our main development environment web server, the HTTP requests are no longer being tracked.

Everything else, including exception, dependencies, traces, are all being tracked properly. But HTTP requests are not. How can I find the cause of this issue? I'm not sure where to start.

We are using Application Insights SDK 2.5.0.61767. The config file is the same across all machines. Not sure what else could be causing it. Any suggestions welcome.

**EDIT**: I noticed it is also not collecting Server Response Time, Server Requests, and Failed Requests.

I have the following module configuration in the ApplicationInsights.config file:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
  <Handlers>
    <!-- 
    Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

    NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
    -->
    <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler</Add>
    <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
    <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
  </Handlers>
</Add>
```

Comment: is this deployed on IIS?  which version?

Comment: @rogerdeuce it is deployed to IIS 8.5

Comment: maybe you're missing a specific telemetry module on the server?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-configuration-with-applicationinsights-config  Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule

Comment: I checked the ApplicationInsights.config file and verified that this module is present. I've added more details in my question.

Comment: googling that module in particular it looks like they are having a ton of issues with it in 2.4 and 2.5.  Not what you want to hear, but it may not be something that you're doing wrong

Comment: The thing is, it works fine from local developer machines....

Comment: yeah blizz I'm seeing the same thing all over.  One person had a transform that was supposed to help it.  https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/569 you can read through the reports here, but they're all works local, does not once deployed

Comment: @rogerdeuce please add your last comment as an answer because it ultimately led to the solution for this issue :)

Comment: which part of github thread helped to solve the problem? something was missing in AI.config?

Comment: @ZakiMa check my answer for details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the following section to my `web.config` has fixed the issue for me.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="integratedMode,managedHandler" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsHttpModule" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```